# How to throw an exception from Jasper Report at Runtime (using iReport for IDE) - Data Validation on XML Datasource

Tags: java, exception, jasper-reports, ireport, validation

For an `XML` data source based report....

If bad data is passed in, it would be nice to fail the report with an informative message such as `variableXYZ` is `0` rather than have a divide by zero error at runtime.

Or, `variableXYZ` must be specified rather than a `NPE` or a default value.  In some cases there are no good defaults that are not misleading.

Is there a way to validate data from an `XML` data source and throw exceptions or somehow notify the user that the data coming in is invalid?

I tried the ternary operator with the else part something like:

```
throw new RuntimeException("VariableXYZ is invalid: 0")
```

but it dies when evaluating the expression.

> 263: unexpected token: throw @ line 263, column 49.

Lastly, I would like to do this without scripting, just as part of the stock `iReport`.  Is this possible?  Are there other good ways to validate data that result in a decent error message?

Comment: The *iReport* is the IDE for building report's templates. Are you really talking about *iReport*?

Comment: I used the term iReport, because many are not aware that jasper is the engine underneath the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible.

The expressions used in the JasperReports environment are literally "Java expressions" (at least when you're using Java as your report language). According to [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html):

> An expression is a construct made up of variables, operators, and method invocations, which are constructed according to the syntax of the language, that evaluates to a single value.

So basically, you can't evaluate the `throw` structure to a value. You can't write `myVar = throw RuntimeException("...");`.

But at the same time you can invoke methods in an expression, so maybe you can add to your class path a method that throws errors, for example.